# azure search sort and filter by score

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I want to know how to filter and order the results by score with azure search.

I tried :

```
https://domaine.net/indexes/indexName/docs?search=TEST$orderby=@search.score%20desc&$count=true
```

Return :

```
object(stdClass)#322 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#323 (2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["message"]=>
    string(96) "Invalid expression: Syntax error at position 8 in '@search.score asc'.
Parameter name: $orderby"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Results are sorted by score (descending) by default. If you sort by other criteria, score is used to break ties. If you want to sort by score explicitly, you can use the `search.score()` function in the `$orderby` parameter. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#order-by-syntax).

It's not currently possible to filter by score. Since score varies as a function of not only the query but also the data corpus, I would be curious to understand your scenario better for filtering based on a score number.

Comment: I'm also interested to filter by Score. I would like to omit results with lower relevance, even to do the filtering by myself, but I don't find any documentation on the scoring range. for example, searching: "Sun protection", I would like to recive all results with "Sun protection" but not results with "sun" or "protection" @Pablo Castro

Answer (score 0):

You can control the results in your application. After de Azure returns the relevant documents, you can choose a range of score to show and hide. I'm trying to define a range but I dont know yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).