# Defining thresholds on Azure Search Score

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

All,
              We have a case in our application where we collect user satisfaction feedback for matches returned from Azure Search for our data. What we have noticed so far from the limited feedback we have is that there is a correlation between scores to user satisfaction (high scores result in better user satisfaction because a more useful match was found). When Azure Search scores are above 2.5, that seems to result in Happy rating for our application. But we’re not sure if this is just a coincidence and whether this approach is even sound.
              We don’t know what is maximum range ( like 0-10) for Azure Search scores. Also this link seem to state the score would vary as a function of the data corpus also ( even when considering that the same query is used with different input data in our case).Is it even possible to define thresholds on Azure Search scores where we can drop significantly low-score matches and not show them at all to the user in our application? Are there any recommendations around this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364573

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply to the question you linked is accurate. The score value is dependent on the corpus you have in your index as it uses variables such as "document frequency" which depends on the documents you have in your index. As such, the same query-document pair could have a different score when calculated in the context of two different indexes.

There also isn't any specific range to that score as it is not meant to be used as an absolute value to be compared between results of different queries. The scoring value is meant to be used to rank the relative relevancy of documents to a specific query, within the same index.

However, since the score is returned as part of the search results, nothing is preventing you to use your own client side filtering within your application to dismiss results that have a score below a certain threshold if you have concluded that it makes sense in the context of your product.

Comment: Thanks, @ramero-MSFT, for the clarification.